# Is there a source build available for the libxslt development package?

Tags: lxml, libxslt, opkg

I am trying to install lxml on a ReMarkable tablet, and while the opkg entware repo has libxslt, it does not contain a package for libxslt-dev. I was wondering if anyone has links to a source build or even better an ipkg file. I've been scouring the internet for the better part of 2 hours, but I'm not even sure I'm looking in the right places. Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same issue and circumvented it by installing `opkg install python-lxml`.

This avoids compiling the module and thus doesn't need libxslt's header files.